# Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to create a Generic eventPublisher for my microservices.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

@EnableBinding(TaskEventStreams.class)
public class EventPublisher {

    private final TaskEventStreams source;

    @Autowired
    public EventPublisher(TaskEventStreams source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void publishEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        publishEvent(event, event.getTenant());
    }

    public void publishEvent(BaseEvent event, String key) {

        source.taskEventOutput().send(
                MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(event)
                        .copyHeaders(event.getHeaders())
                        .setHeader("partitionKey", key)
                        .build());
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;

public interface TaskEventStreams {
    String TASK_EVENT_OUTPUT = "task-event-output";

    @Output(TASK_EVENT_OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel taskEventOutput();
}
```

Application properties

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: kafka
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          auto-create-topics: true
      bindings:
        task-event-output:
          destination: tasks
          group: tasks
          binder: kafka
          contentType: application/json
```

This service will only publish the events. These events then later can be consumed by other services. But when I am trying to publish the event I am getting below exception

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    EventPublisher eventPublisher;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        BaseEvent event = TaskCreatedEvent.builder().tenant("tenant").build();
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'task-event-output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[255], headers={id=06b61f95-24d8-7f35-3e57-9ae262c2ca47, partitionKey=tenant, contentType=application/json, tenant=tenant, timestamp=1675063077441}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[255], headers={id=06b61f95-24d8-7f35-3e57-9ae262c2ca47, partitionKey=tenant, contentType=application/json, tenant=tenant, timestamp=1675063077441}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
```

Is there a limitation that without consumer we cannot have producer? or am I missing something with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    BaseEvent event = TaskCreatedEvent.builder().tenant("tenant").build();
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
}
```

That's too early to interact with low-level resource. You really cannot send message to the broker while your application is still in a configuration phase.

See into an `ApplicationRunner` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.command-line-runner

Comment: Thanks. I used the `ApplicationReadyEvent` instead